# QGIS WFS data hidden under map

Tags: qgis

This is my first time using QGIS.

I downloaded some WFS (http://www.gdos.gov.pl/access-to-geospatial-data) data to use on the Natural Earth QuickStart Kit map (http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html).

The WFS layers have been added, however they are hidden under the map, rather than being on the map.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the order of your layers. The layers at the top are displayed over anything that's below them. So if your map is over the WFS then it would hide it.

Comment: @polarsandwich - Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)